# Get Dropdown's Name or ID

Tags: jquery

I have five dropdowns and when one changes I want to update the list of options in the other dropdowns. Currently I am using the code below. Right now I am just displaying the string. Once I get this part working I will pass the string to another page that will run some queries to get the new lists of values for the other dropdowns and then rebuild the dropdowns. I am open to suggestions on my method, but currently here's my hurdle: how do I get the name (or ID) of the dropdown. I am using .each for brevity, as I do know the names and IDs I could use five selectors, but I thought this was better.

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).attr('name') + " ";
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    window.alert(str);
}).change();
```

Also, this code fires as the dropdowns are built initially. How do I prevent that? So my questions are how do I get the name or ID? Trying $(this).attr('name') here. How do I prevent this from running the first time the dropdowns are built? Is there a better method to rebuild the dropdowns?

**Working Code**

```
$("select").change(function() {
var str = "";
$("select option:selected").each(function() {
    str += $(this).parent().attr('id') + " ";
    str += $(this).text() + " ";
});
window.alert(str);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3m67g/)

Comment: what do you mean by id ?

Comment: I think I see the issue. Because I am doing .each for the selected option and not the select element itself.

Comment: <select name="theName" id="theID">

Comment: If you still have problems, please create a jsfiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/ where we can help you realtime.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, You're firing the event after you add the handler.. 
remove the   `.change();` after your event definitinon.

Secondly, You want to get the ID of the dropdown (from the selected option?) so you can get the `$(this).parent().attr('id')` or `$(this).parent().id;`

-- if not from the selected option - `$(this).id` will be ok.

```
     $("select")
            .change(function() {
                var str = "";

                    alert($(this).id); //select id

                     $(this).find('option').each(function() {
                        str += $(this).attr('name') + " ";

                        alert($(this).parent().id); //select id..

                        str += $(this).text() + " ";
                     });
                 window.alert(str);
            });
```

Comment: to get the id - "this.id" should suffice.

Comment: yep cheers, did a tonne of edits got preoccupied with something else.. thanks :)

Comment: I'm going to have to make a jsfiddle. I get undefined for the id here and it's giving me the list of values and not just the selected value. I want to get the id and the corresponding selected value of each dropdown anytime any of them are changed.

Comment: Nevermind, read your full response better. Here's what worked:
`$("select").change(function() {
    var str = "";
    $("select option:selected").each(function() {
        str += $(this).parent().attr('id') + " ";
        str += $(this).text() + " ";
    });
    window.alert(str);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

Demo: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lshettyl/PV6tW/1/)

HTML

```
<select name="s1" id="ss1"><option value="1">ONE</option><option value="2">TWO</option></select>
<select name="s2" id="ss2"><option value="1">ONE</option><option value="2">TWO</option></select>
<select name="s3" id="ss3"><option value="1">ONE</option><option value="2">TWO</option></select>
<select name="s4" id="ss4"><option value="1">ONE</option><option value="2">TWO</option></select>
<select name="s5" id="ss5"><option value="1">ONE</option><option value="2">TWO</option></select>
```

JS

```
$(function(){
    $('select').change(function() {
        var str = "";
        $('select').each(function(i){
            str += "id: " + this.id + "\n";
            str += "name: " + $(this).attr("name") + "\n\n\n";
        });
        alert (str);
    });
});
```